# How to use one UIDatePicker for multiple UITextFields?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uidatepicker, inputview

In my `viewDidLoad` I have the following Code:

```
UIDatePicker* datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
dateField1.inputView = datePicker;
dateField2.inputView = datePicker;
dateField3.inputView = datePicker;
dateField4.inputView = datePicker;
```

(The dateField's are all `UITextField`s)

In my `-(void)datePickerChanged:(UIDatePicker*)datePicker`
method, how do I know which dateField is being edited, so that I can fill in the picked date?

Currently I am using a new UIDatePicker for each UITextField, but I hope there is a more elegant solution for this situation.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if([textField1 isFirstResponder]) {

}
else if[textField2 isFirstResponder]){

}

...etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up different tags for your dateFields and check what field was changed in datePickerChanged: method. But to do it you should store original results in another place (for example in dictionary where your dateField's tags will be a keys). I did not tried this before but should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help!, but by setting the datePicker as the inputView doesn't automatically fill the textField if a value has been picked (so there is nothing changed). I am using the datePickerChanged: method to fill in the dateField. And so I still don't know which dateField is being edited